# Tricky counter intuitive riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am green.
>
> I also tickle and irritate.
>
> I am essential but when in a different avatar **I am not**.
>
> I live on dogs and in forest.

**Who am I ?**

Answer (score 8):

You're

> A tick

I am green.

> The green tick in SE (the checkmark I hope I'll get).

I also tickle and irritate.

> The blood-sucking insect.

I am essential but when in a different avatar I am not.

> We all like the green tick, but not when another one gets it.

I live in dogs and in forest.

> The tick (animal) lives in the forest and is commonly found feasting upon dogs.

Comment: So this is essentially a rot13(gvpxl evqqyr), not a tricky one, eh? :-)

Comment: If this is the answer it makes me wonder why it's **in** a dog rather than **on** a dog...

Comment: @dcfyj It may be a grammar mistake, many people here aren't native english speakers and we may make weird errors :p

Comment: This is true :P

Comment: You are very close but that is not the answer

Comment: I edited the question for grammar mistake (changed in to on)

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be

> A flea

I am green

> The artist named Flea from the band Red Hot Chili Pepper is an environmental activist

I also tickle and irritate.

> Fleas are a blood sucking parasite

I am essential but when in a different avatar I am not.

> In face of danger it might be essential to **flee** (different spelling wich could be what you meant with different avatar), though fleas themselves might not appear as essential

I live on dogs and in forest.

> Fleas are often found parasiting dogs and in nature

Comment: Flea is the right answer but your explanation is wrong.

Comment: I have written the correct explanation

Answer (score 4):

Could you be

> fur / fir ?

I am green.

> Fir trees are green

I also tickle and irritate.

> Fur can tickle; some people have allergies to pine needles

I am essential but when in a different avatar I am not.

> A fir tree cannot live without it's needles; a mammal may survive without its fur

I live on dogs and in forest.

> Dogs have fur; forests may have fir trees

Comment: Nice wordplay in your answer!

Comment: That is not correct. Sorry

Comment: This answer is the most apt one of all, I feel.

Answer (score 0):

I have no full explanation, but something hints that it can be a

> tick.

It does tickle, irritate and is naturally found in forests & dogs.

As for everything else,

> A tick ☑ is usually green (essential, though?) and has same meaning as naught (○).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the earlier provided answers and my intuition, I would like to go with

> GNAT

As,

> It satisfies most of the description and also the highlighted / bold lettered hint *phonetically* :-)

Comment: Typically for riddles we do line by line explanations to make it clear why you think it's the answer.

Comment: Nope not the answer